# PHP Error: Function name must be a string / Undefined Variable send_sms

Tags: php

```
if(!empty($_GET['new_time'])){

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE id=".$_GET['new_time'];
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $mobile_number = $rows['mobile_number'];
    // Create instance with key
    $key = 'AIzaSyD1tPfs4s2dYYHMkCOqNZoVsTkDyud-9Yg';
    $googer = new GoogleURLAPI($key);


    $message = lang_content(98, $rows['preferred_language'])." ".$shortDWName;
    $send_sms($mobile_number,$message,$city_id);
}
```

If someone triggers the new_time, I get this error.

> send_sms is a function to send a message.

Comment: remove `$` sign from `send_sms` function, so call function like - `send_sms($mobile_number,$message,$city_id);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to add `$` in function name while calling that function:

just use `send_sms($mobile_number,$message,$city_id);`

Answer (score 1):

you can call function by calling its name

```
send_sms($mobile_number,$message,$city_id);
```

or

declare a variable and make a function call in that variable

```
$sendsms=send_sms($mobile_number,$message,$city_id);
```